# What is the probability that a 4-digit pin number contains a 1 and 5 (assuming repeats)?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I tried to find different way the 1 and 5 would show in place.
For example it could be 1 _ 5 _ or 5 _ 1 _ or 1 5 _ _ and so forth.. This is how I got there are 12 possibilities to rearrange 1 and 5 in a 4 digit pin number.
But how do I include the other values into this and incorporate it?

Comment: As a suggestion:  it is easier to work backwards.  Compute the probability that your string *does not* contain both $1,5$.    Note:  you should indicate whether all $10$ digits are allowed or not.  Is $0000$ a valid pin?

Answer (score 1):

The question is to find the number of $4$ digit pins if both $1$ and $5$ must be included in them.

This is a straight application of inclusion-exclusion.
Assuming that $0000$ is admissible,

Number of ways = (Total ways) - (At least one desired digit missing) + (Both desired digits missing)

$ = 10^4 -\binom219^4 + \binom228^4 = 974$

Answer (score 0):

We want to find the chance that both $1$ and $5$ were *not chosen*.

First off, if there is only a single one or a single five, we can choose to place this $1$ or $5$ in only $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.  Then we have to pick whether it is a $1$ or a $5$, which can be done in $2$ ways.  Finally, we pick the remaining three numbers.  There are 8 choices for each of them, for a total of $8^3$ choices or trials.  This gives us a total of $\binom{4}{1} \cdot 2 \cdot 8^{4-1}$ ways.

Similarly, for two $1$s or two $5$s, there are $\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot 8^{4-2}$ ways.  For three of them, there are $\binom{4}{3} \cdot 2 \cdot 8^{4-3}$ ways.  By now you should know the pattern.

There is also the chance that no $1$ or $5$ was chosen, which can happen any of $8^4$ ways.

This gives us a total of

$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^{4}{\binom{4}{k} \cdot 2 \cdot 8^{4-k} } \right)+8^4 = 9026$$
trials, out of either 10,000 if you consider the combination $0000$ as valid, or 9,999 if you do not.